# How to know the recommended/suggested packages using terminal?

Tags: linux, package-management, aptitude

In synaptic if you right-click a package you will see a sub-menu called recommended and another sub-menu called suggested.

How can I see the recommended and suggested packages for a specific package in the terminal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `aptitude show`. For example:

```
aptitude show vlc
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `aptitude search` with `?reverse-depType(pattern)`:

For example

```
aptitude search '?reverse-recommends(?narrow(?version(CURRENT),^freemind$))'
```

will show you the recommends of the currently installed freemind package.

Note that you should use `^packagename$` and not just `packagename`, because otherwise you will also find the recommends of packages containing `packagename` in their name.

And you might want to use `?narrow(?version(CURRENT), ...)` or something similiar to show only the recommends of the current version, otherwise you will see the recommends of all available versions in the repositories.

For suggests use `?reverse-suggests` instead.

Also you can look at the [Search Term Reference](http://algebraicthunk.net/~dburrows/projects/aptitude/doc/en/ch02s03s05.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
apt-cache depends PACKAGE
```

or, to get also other info on the PACKAGE, use:

```
apt-cache showpkg PACKAGE
```

Comment: Without sudo please.

Comment: Corrected: sudo was not necessary.  I was just used to use sudo at each invocation of `apt-*` commands.

Comment: Some of the output for this command can get quite long, I like `apt-cache depends PACKAGE | grep -E '(Rec|Sug}'` to filter just for the important stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `info` flag

```
apt info package-name
```

or more succinctly

```
apt info package-name | grep -B 1 'Recommends'
```